# Grand Canonical Ensemble for finite particle system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Suppose I have a system of a finite number of lattice sites, Say M, and binding energy of the particle to be $-\epsilon$. The system is in equilibrium and the chemical potential is $\mu$. Multiple occupancies of the sites are forbidden.

---

The grand partition function can be written as
$$\mathcal{Q}=\sum_{N=0}^Mz^NZ_N$$
where $Z_N$ and $z$ are canonical partition function and fugacity. *Is it right to write the sum up to some limit?* Supposing this  to be true then
$$Z_N= {}^MC_N e^{-N\beta \epsilon}+{}^{M}C_{M-N}e^0$$
$$\mathcal{Q}=\sum_{N=0}^Mz^N( {}^MC_N e^{-N\beta \epsilon}+{}^{M}C_{M-N})$$
*Is this expression is correct?*

Comment: What is the superscript on the left supposed to denote?

Comment: It's Combinatorics. It's degeneracy that I have taken into account. There are $M$ sites and $N$ particles so I have written the combinations.

Comment: I see, it may be worth mentioning in OP because I don't believe that's the most common notation for the binomial coefficients.

Comment: In any case, you have answered your own question about the upper limit by stating *multiple occupancies of the sites are forbidden* since the sum over $N$ here is the sum over the number of particles.

Comment: Yeah but there are many lattice sites (degeneracy) and particles can occupy them. There is $M$ lattice sites so I did take the sum from $0$ to $M$, Is it correct or not?